# What are some good techniques for getting class name in C++?

Tags: c++, types, polymorphism, typing, classname

I'm NOT talking about typeid, I'm just looking for general method to bind a single object (e.g. std::string like in my case) to objects of some class and make its getter polymorphic or something. I can't really give a proper definition so i think that it's just like the problem of getting a class name but you set it yourself somewhere and the only problems are where do you set it and how do you return it.

I'm just gonna give a few examples that do what I want but aren't really as efficient as I want them to be.

- `virtual string GetClassName() const { return string("MyClass"); }` - consumes extra time to build and copy a string every time it is called
- `const string& GetClassName() const { return class_name_; }` where `class_name_` is a protected class field that is set in the constructor -  the same string is stored in every object, thus it is not memory-efficient

I'm thinking about something like returning a const reference to a static object, but I can't really find a way to make it polymorphic.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware of static class attributes? They exist only once globally are initialised only once.

Comment: `virtual const string& GetClassName() const { return my_static_class_name; }`

Comment: Please exend your shown code to a full class example. That will make giving an answer easier.

Comment: now that i think of it, it makes sense... did i get this right and this stuff has to be copied into every class of mine and there is no way to avoid code duplication?

Comment: This is the draw-back of that solution. Any class has to provide this, at least, any non-abstract. Every class has to overload the resp. virtual method. Thereby, the code might be everytimes literally the same. In our case, we used convenience macros (yeah, macros :-( ) for this (to prevent typos). However, if you forget this for one class, it might inherit it from its base class and reply wrong result at runtime. I don't know any technique which could this turn into a compile-time check.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to reinvent the wheel, when you can just extend it with the right tire.

The C++standard gives you [`typeid()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) that works in all the the cases, including built-in types, custom classes, polymorphic classes, multiple inheritance, virtual inheritance and things like that.

Now you may not like the names used by `typeid()`, which are implementation specific. Or you may want to extend the information available with your own type management extensions.  In this case, Bjarne Stroustrup proposed in "*The design and evolution of C++*" a very simple and effective solution.

The `typeid()` returns a reference to a `const std::type_info`.  Now you can use the address of this object in a [`unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/unordered_map), to map the type to your own custom information that could provide the name you want.

The advantage of this solution:  uses robust built-in capability, is based on a single additional object per class (could be static), very low overhead to get to the name. all you need to do is to think about how to best populate the map.

Here a small and quick proof of concept (must be improved of course):

```
// Basic principle of the idea
map<const type_info*, string> mytypes;  

template <class T>
const string& mytype(T &&x) {
    return mytypes[&typeid(x)];
}

// Some test types 
struct A { virtual int test() {} };
struct B : A {}; 

int main() {
    // To be improved:  initialization of the type info extension 
    mytypes[&typeid(int)]="Plain C++ integer";
    mytypes[&typeid(A)]="Structure A";
    mytypes[&typeid(B)]="Structure B";

    // demo, including polymorphic type     
    int a; 
    A * p = new B;
    cout << typeid(int).name() <<endl; 
    cout << mytype(a) <<endl; 
    cout << mytype(*p) <<endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/2NiWiE)

Comment: An additional advantage: you can check at runtime whether class was registered properly. (A non-registered class might run into an `assert()` when asked for its name.)

Answer (score 1):

What I think you want is some base `NamedClass` with a `virtual std::string_view getName() const` that returns the name of the derived class. So you want something like `typeid(object).name()` but without the name mangling.

Every class that derives from `NamedClass` should override `getName` and return the class name.

```
class NamedClass {
public:
  virtual std::string_view getName() const = 0;
};

class Derived final : public NamedClass {
public:
  std::string_view getName() const override {
    return "Derived";
  }
};
```

If you hate this duplication as much as I do, you could use a macro.

```
#define GET_NAME(NAME) \
  std::string_view getName() const override { return #NAME; }

class Derived final : public NamedClass {
public:
  GET_NAME(Derived)
};
```

I highly recommend using a `std::string_view` instead of a `const std::string &` if all you want to do is "view" the string.

Comment: Interesting. The constraint of sharing a base class seems however very strong. Furthermore, what how would this work in case of multiple inheritance?

Comment: @Christophe In the case of multiple inheritance, you would  virtually inherit from `NamedClass` to avoid the deadly diamond.